# Extended calendar which runs on 1st business day of 3rd of every month in autosys

Tags: calendar, autosys

I need to create extended calendar which will run on 1st business day of 3rd week of every month. 
Mon to Fri are considered as working day and no holiday calendar included. 
Sample dates for year 2018 : 
16th Jan, 13th Feb, 13th Mar, 17th Apr, 15th May, 12th Jun, 17th Jul, 14th Aug, 11th Sep, 16th Oct, 13th Nov, 11th Dec

Currently I am using standard calendar for this but wants to change it to extended calendar to avoid manual inserts for every year.

Comment: Please put the code you tried!!

Comment: I am not 100% clear which code you are asking for, but below is the definition for standard calendar which we are currently using.

Calendar_Name: CAL_ABC
Description: 1st Business day of 3rd week for every month
Date: 01/16/2018
Date: 02/13/2018
Date: 03/13/2018
Date: 04/17/2018
Date: 05/15/2018
Date: 06/12/2018
Date: 07/17/2018
Date: 08/14/2018
Date: 09/11/2018
Date: 10/16/2018
Date: 11/13/2018
Date: 12/11/2018

So generally we mention static dates while creating standard calendar, which we need to update every year. Hope this helps in understanding my question

Answer (score 0):

@Manvi

not very confident of the exact condition and this would be a partial answer.
as for now i can think of

```
WEEK#03|WEEK#07|WEEK#11|WEEK#15|WEEK#20|WEEK#24|WEEK#28|WEEK#33|WEEK#37|WEEK#42|WEEK#46|WEEK#50
```

This would give you all the 3rd week of the the months and then hereon need to exclude the rest of the days.

You can refer this [link](https://docops.ca.com/ca-workload-automation-ae/11-4-2/en/scheduling/ae-scheduling/manage-your-calendars/date-condition-keywords) for condition keywords.

Also, you can use below to include multiple keywords for desired output.

OR condition as "|"

NOT as "NOT"

Hope this helps. Good luck.
Will update incase i do find the solution.

Edits:

The first working day would definitely be a Monday and the previous day has to be 2nd Sunday.

Consider a calender as below

> extended_calendar: Cal_name
>
> description: 1st day of the 3rd week
>
> workday: mo,tu,we,th,fr
>
> non_workday:
>
> holiday:
>
> holcal:
>
> cyccal:
>
> adjust: +1
>
> condition: sun#2

**Sun#2** would consider the 2nd sunday of all months and the next day would mark the start of the 3rd week.
To consider the next day of the 2nd sunday **adjust: +1** defined.

If you are looking for the 2nd day of the 3rd week. Defined adjust to +2.

Comment: Thanks piyush !! But we have one issue with the condition you have mentioned. The keyword WEEK#nn considers week from the year, which won't work here because sometimes we have 5 week in a month and because of that we cannot give which week to pickup in every month

Comment: Pls try out the other way pointed below edits in the answers.
This should work.